# Azure table storage service exception

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to log some of my data to Azure table storage service and it was working fine till now. I am logging to Azure table storage using Java.
Suddenly from yesterday I am getting the error as below:

Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceException

I read some articles on google https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/171 and it talks about blobs. I could not find anything related to table storage.

Can someone help me on this one? Code to access table is usual as below.

```
  private CloudTable GetCloudTableContainer(String tableName) {
    CloudTable table = null;
    try {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(config.CONNECTION_STRING);

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();
        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        table = tableClient.getTableReference(tableName);
        table.createIfNotExists();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're using storage account name and key in your connection string, please check for 2 things: 1) Your storage account key has not changed & 2) Clock on the computer is fairly accurate and not running behind. In my experience, these two are the main reasons for this error.

Comment: @GauravMantri when you say clock on the computer, meaning clock of the server machine right?

Comment: That's correct. Time on the machine where this code is running.

Comment: @user1955255 Any update now?

Comment: Any update. Facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using shared acces signature(SAS)? Maybe it has expired?

Comment: No I am not using SAS